# How Create Callback options before and after Plugin jQuery?

Tags: jquery, plugins, callback

How Create Callback options before and after Plugin jQuery???

```
$('#slide').myPlugin({
   onBefore:function(){
      alert('Start slide images');
   },
   onAfter:function(){
      alert('End slide !');
   }
});
```

Plese help demo !

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#slide').slider({
  start:function(event, ui){
  alert('Start slide images');
},
stop:function(event, ui){
  alert('End slide !');
 }
});
```

Please refer [link](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-start)

Comment: Could you please explain it bit more? ... Are you creating your own plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Totally depends on how you structure your plugin code. The simplest case would be:

```
(function($) {

  // Constructor
  var MyPlugin = function(element, options) {
    this.element = element
    this.options = options
    // ...
  }

  MyPlugin.prototype.slide = function() {
    this.options.onBefore && this.options.onBefore.call(this)
    // Do your stuff
    this.options.onAfter && this.options.onAfter.call(this)
  }

  // Default options
  var defaults = {}

  // jQuery chainable
  $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
    options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).data('myPlugin', new MyPlugin(this, options))
    })
  } 

}(jQuery))
```

However, you'd better use event (not callback) for this kind of function.